# align text to top of a button without using a span inside it

Tags: html, css, button, text, vertical-alignment

I want to vertical align text to the top of a button, but I do not want to use any span or div within the button.How can I do it?
`vertical-align:top` does not help

The text within the button will be multiline and it is not fixed.Length of text can vary....It can either occupy only first line or be multiline..So I cannot fix some padding

Comment: have you tried to do `padding-top:0px;`?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `padding-bottom` of the button to 75%. This will push the text up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to stick to the top you can just add padding to the button and then take away the padding at the top of the button.

```
.btn { padding: 10px; padding-top: 0px;}
```

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LJ3NL/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `line-height` for `button` and than give `padding-bottom`. This will vertical align text to top.

Comment: Set the `line-height` to what?

Comment: set line-height to button which removes the top spacing in button

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="button" />
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    background: #000000;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    height:100px;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nZJJb/)

Comment: What's with all the extra styles?

Answer (score 0):

Please This css try it

```
  input {height:auto; padding-bottom:30px; }
```

[image]